# Starting location setting page

Tags: android, location, settings

In my app I need to bring up the location settings page if location is not enabled.

This is done by

```
Intent  intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);

startActivity(intent);
```

It works OK, however, once the setting page is finished with, I find I have to tap the back button several times to get back to my app, and on an HTC phone, the setting page sometimes crashes (my app is OK).

Other apps that do this do not seem to have these problems, are there any suggestions as to what they do that I don't?

The code aove is called directly from a View touch event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity, before starting location source settings, register a broadcast receiver for `android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED` and when you received the broadcast start your activity and unregister your receiver. You might also want to make your activity single-instance.

Comment: Wasn't that, thatnks. That just stopped by app from coming up at all. Sorted it - completely my mistake. Owing to the program flow it makages to stack up several of these setting dialogues by mistake.